# Is there a function corresponding to "\" in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, path

I would like to implement the concatenation of paths to files using "\" as an operator, redefining the corresponding function (if any).

For example:

```
path1 = '\home'
path2 = 'codes'

codepath = path1 \ path2
```

Thus, adding str "\" between path1 and path2 in the redefition of the method, I should assert `codepath = '\home\codes'`

Comment: You can't; not with backslash and not with standard types. Backslash is used to indicate a line continuation in Python expressions. You *could* use existing operators such as `/`, but you need a custom type to override the behaviour of the operator.

Comment: How about `os.path.join('home', 'codes')`?

Comment: Python 3.4 has a new module [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pathlib.html) that does effectively this, except with `/` as the operator.

Comment: Take a look at the new Python 3.4 library [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) for a module that already uses `/` to join path elements.

Comment: I need to do it in Python 2.7 for compatibility with standars functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`pathlib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/) module supports `/` for concatenating path objects.

```
>>> p = Path('/etc')
>>> q = p / 'init.d' / 'reboot'
>>> q
PosixPath('/etc/init.d/reboot')
>>> q.resolve()
PosixPath('/etc/rc.d/init.d/halt')
```

As an example of how to use `__div__`, here's a simple class that extends `str`. It should work as long as at least one argument is an instance of `MyPath` (i.e., it won't work with two plain strings).

```
class MyPath(str):
    def __div__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, str)
        return os.path.join(self, other)
    def __rdiv__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, str)
        return os.path.join(other, self)

# Using __div__
print MyPath("/home/bob") / MyPath("bin")
print MyPath("/home/bob") / "bin"

# Using __rdiv__
print "/home/bob" / MyPath("bin")
```

Comment: This is not standard in python 2.7 because it requires installation. I must do it with python 2.7 standard moludes because it will be used on various machines with 2.7 native (with no extra packages for compatibility)

Comment: Then you're going to have to use `os.path.join`. The backslash is a non-starter, because it's not already an operator and you can't simply add new syntax. You could implement your own class to represent file paths and define `__div__` yourself to use `/`, but at that point you might as well just package `pathlib` with your code.

Comment: That's the way to solve it. I will use the operator "/" and redefinire "div" in my class. Thank you chep

Comment: How i can use / (__div__) to concatenate strings with "/"???
I get: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: edit your answer with your first comment (implements __div__ method) and i'll accept the answer.